# Nodejs upload a model to shapeways api

Tags: node.js, 3d, webgl

I am trying to upload a obj file to shapeways api. I tried using the request module by creating the url. It doesn't seem to be working. Could someone show me some code examples? The documentation only mentions php

Thanks

```
fs.readFile("/models/temp.obj",function(err,data){

   var params  = {file:data,
                  filename:"temp.obj",
                  hasRightsToModel: 1, 
                  acceptTermsAndConditions: 1}

   var client = new shapeways.client({ consumerKey: config.app.key, 
                                consumerSecret: config.app.secret, 
                                oauthToken: req.session.oauthToken, 
                                oauthSecret: req.session.oauthSecret, }); 

                client.addModel(params,callback);

 })
```

Here's the code. The fs.readfile returns undefined.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to share some code, and ask a specific question

Comment: I am using the node-shapeways api. here I define the client.

Comment: I have edited my question. Does this help? The example in shapeways documentation has a php example where the file is read using file_get_contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My params had filename. It should have been fileName. Silly mistake. Everything else I had incorporated anyways. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code has two issues.

One you don't specify your root dir, I doubt you really mean /models.
And two you should never ignore the err parameter.

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + "/models/temp.obj", function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  // . . .
});
```